# how to assign variable value to jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
 var s="attr"
  var i=$(s)
  // jQuery(elem).attr(attr,eval("elm"+attr));
  jQuery(elem).$(s)(attr,eval("elm"+attr));//i tried this.
```

how to assign a variable name in the above code(in place of s) so that i need to add an attribute the the element "elem".

Comment: What are the rules of the conversion? How come you `NO` is changed to `Rollno`? And 70 to 1020?!

Comment: Sorry. I Mistakenly added so. There are no rules.I just want to convert an xml to json format. The only thing is i want to do this in vb.net windows application.

Comment: Your updated code is not XML. `<RollNO="70"></Roll>` can't be valid, for several reasons. Could you provide a proper sample?

Comment: i am new to JSON and xml. so kindly forgive me if any fault is there. What i need is converting xml to json using xslt in windows application.

Comment: Using XSLT? That completely changes the question. Why didn't you say so in the first place?

Comment: after had a little googling i decided to use this. How else can do in vb.net? if any alternatives pls explain.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick search I found this ready made [XML to JSON stylesheet](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/xsltjson/) which looks like it should serve you well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..When i tried to transform it using W3School XSLT editor it throws error. given the link below. http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_if

Comment: What was the error and how were you importing the XML to JSON stylesheet?

Comment: By the way those links you are posting don't show anything outside of your own session.

Answer (score 0):

JSON and XML aren't really compatible, so you have to figure out how to convert between them. For example, in XML, you often have several elements with the same name as siblings (you could have another `<ROLL>`). In JSON, you have to represent this using an array. But if you use a rule like “when more than one sibling element has the same name in XML, they form a JSON array”, you won't get consistent results. Many elements will produce array, one will produce normal object and zero will produce nothing.

With keeping caveats like this in mind, and using LINQ to XML and [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/), you could do it like this:

```vb
Function Process(element As XElement) As JObject
    Dim result = New JObject

    For Each attribute In element.Attributes()
        result.Add(attribute.Name.LocalName, attribute.Value)
    Next

    Dim elementGroups = element.Elements().GroupBy(Function(e) e.Name)

    For Each elementGroup In elementGroups
        If elementGroup.Count() = 1 Then
            result.Add(elementGroup.Key.LocalName, Process(elementGroup.Single()))
        Else
            Dim array = New JArray

            For Each child In elementGroup
                array.Add(Process(child))
            Next

            result.Add(elementGroup.Key.LocalName, array)
        End If
    Next

    Return result
End Function
```